# How to remove third party favicon on my site?

Tags: php, javascript, html

When submitting a form on my site, the user is redirected to the third party email campaigns site. When redirected back to my site the favicon of the third remains on my page. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Do you have a favicon of your own? How do you link it? In what browser(s) does this happen?

Comment: Well, do you have a favicon of your own?

Comment: No i dont. My client hasn't supplied one yet.

Comment: @jmag: What happens when you create an empty favicon (a favicon that's all transparent)?

Comment: @Piskvor: I hadn't thought of that. I will try it now. thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Don't forget to link it in your HTML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you don't have a favicon on the site itself (If you don't want/have a favicon that you'd want to use, you can use an empty image for a favicon).

For best compatibility, I'd suggest having both a `/favicon.ico`, and a `link` to it in your HTML document, as seen e.g. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility